# Is there any difference between using router.route() and app.<post,get...>?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm building the REST API for my application (It's a large app) so i decided to make it modular, here's what i've done so far to handle the routes:

**/server/modules/purchases/products/index.js**

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express        = require( 'express' ),
        router         = express.Router(),
        create_product = require( './create-product.controller' ),
        list_product   = require( './list-product.controller' ),
        detail_product = require( './detail-product.controller' ),
        update_product = require( './update-product.controller' );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/new' )
        .post( create_product.post );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/list' )
        .get( list_product.get );

    router.route( '/purchases/products/detail' )
        .get( detail_product.get );

    router.route('/purchases/products/update')
        .put( update_product.put );

    return router;

})();
```

**/server/modules/purchases/products/list-product.controller.js**

```
module.exports = (function () {

    models = require( '../../database/models' );

    function get( request, response ) {
        //Send All Products
    }

    return {
        get: get
    }

})();
```

While searching i found that what others do for routing is:

```
...
var app = express();

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  //Some code...
});
...
```

How is that different from what i've done?, which way is better if they're comparable, also i want to know if it's correct to set the post without a get:

```
router.route( '/purchases/products/new' ).post( create_product.post );
```

Comment: You can use Mean.js (http://meanjs.org/) it will generate the initial app, and module structure for you. It uses app.route() instead of router.route()

Comment: I don't want to use a generator, it's has not a modular structure @Ragnar